# Longest Common Prefix in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to solve the Leet Code challenge [14. Longest Common Prefix](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-prefix/):

> Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings.
>
> If there is no common prefix, return an empty string `""`.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> ```
> Input: strs = ["flower", "flow", "flight"]
> Output: "fl"
> ```
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> ```
> Input: strs = ["dog", "racecar", "car"]
> Output: ""
> ```
>
> **Explanation:** There is no common prefix among the input strings.
>
> ### Constraints:
>
> - `1 <= strs.length <= 200`
> - `0 <= strs[i].length <= 200`
> - `strs[i]` consists of only lower-case English letters.

### My solution:

```js
let strs = ["flower", "flow", "flight"];

const longestCommonPrefix = function (strs) {
  for (let i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < strs[i].length; j++) {
       // console.log(strs[i+2][j]);
      if (strs[i][j] == strs[i + 1][j] && strs[i + 1][j] ==strs[i + 2][j]) {
        return (strs[i][j]);
        
      } else {
        return "0";
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(longestCommonPrefix(strs));
```

Output: `f`

How can I iterate over every character and check if it is same and then go for next and if it fails then the longest common prefix will be returned?

Comment: If you don't know what's wrong: your first course of action is to _find out_ what's wrong. You might not be able to figure out how to fix it once you do, but you _do_ need to put in the time and effort to debug your own code: use a small number as input and put some console logs in your loops, or even better, but a `debugger` statement in and use the browser's debugger to step through your code while watching variables. As you you _know_ what should happen at each iteration, you can pretty quickly spot what's wrong. Also, on a JS note: don't use `var x = function...` , just declare a function.

Comment: I have done these things you have mentioned and also got the answer to why I was getting that output. The thing is how can I check for every character and return the longest common prefix?

Comment: Then you'll want to [update your post](/help/how-to-ask) to explain what you found, where you see it go wrong, and what you already examined to hopefully (but unsuccessfully) fix things.

Comment: An easy solution https://youtu.be/f-JiELCbkOs

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the longest common prefix must occur in every string of the array you can jus iterate over the length and check if all words have the same char at that index until you find a difference

```js
function prefix(words){
  // check border cases size 1 array and empty first word)
  if (!words[0] || words.length ==  1) return words[0] || "";
  let i = 0;
  // while all words have the same character at position i, increment i
  while(words[0][i] && words.every(w => w[i] === words[0][i]))
    i++;
  
  // prefix is the substring from the beginning to the last successfully checked i
  return words[0].substr(0, i);
}

console.log(1, prefix([]));
console.log(2, prefix([""]));
console.log(3, prefix(["abc"]));
console.log(4, prefix(["abcdefgh", "abcde", "abe"]));
console.log(5, prefix(["abc", "abc", "abc"]));
console.log(6, prefix(["abc", "abcde", "xyz"]));
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Can you please tell me what's the time complexity for this solution? As I have also done the same thing but with O(n2) time complexity.

Comment: `let strs = ["flower", "flow", "floght"];

var longestCommonPrefix = function (strs) {
  for (let i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < strs[i].length; j++) {
      while(strs[i][j] == strs[i + 1][j] && strs[i][j] == strs[i + 2][j]){
             j++;
          }
      return String(strs).substr(0,j);
      }
    }
  }

console.log(longestCommonPrefix(strs));
`

Comment: The complexity is `O(n * m)` where `n` is the number of words in the array, and `m` is the length of the prefix

Comment: And, in the first `if` statement, Is it like `Conditional (ternary) operator`? If possible can you please explain this or share documentation where I can learn about this?

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with the ternary operator. In `words[0] || ""` that's a simple OR `||` operator. Ie, if the first operand (`words[0]`) is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) it returns the first operand. If it's a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) it returns the second ...

Comment: Oh. Got it. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Some of the issues:

- Your inner loop will encounter a `return` on its *first* iteration. This means your loops will never repeat, and the return value will always be one character.
- It is wrong to address `strs[i+1]` and `strs[i+2]` in your loop, as those indexes will go out of bounds (`>= strs.length`)

Instead of performing character by character comparison, you could use substring (prefix) comparison (in one operation): this may seem a waste, but as such comparison happens "below" JavaScript code, it is very fast (and as string size limit is 200 characters, this is fine).

The algorithm could start by selecting an existing string as prefix and then shorten it every time there is a string in the input that doesn't have it as prefix. At the end you will be left with the common prefix.

It is good to start with the *shortest* string as the initial prefix candidate, as the common prefix can certainly not be longer than that.

```js
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
    let prefix = strs.reduce((acc, str) => str.length < acc.length ? str : acc);
    
    for (let str of strs) {
        while (str.slice(0, prefix.length) != prefix) {
            prefix = prefix.slice(0, -1);
        }
    }
    return prefix;
};

let res = longestCommonPrefix(["flower","flow","flight"]);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: You are taking the first two strings from the array I guess. Then what if the third-string length is less than the other two? And, if possible can you please explain what this line means `for(let str of strs)`?

Comment: The first line iterates the whole array (using `reduce`) to find the shortest string. See `for...of` in [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). It is just a loop over all the values in the array, without having to maintain an index variable.

Comment: best solution posted so far, good job! PS this code crash with an empty array, but if that's correct behavior or not may be up for debate ;)

Comment: It is in the conditions that the array will have at least a size of 1, so I didn't bother dealing with an empty array.

Answer (score 3):

An approach based on sorting by word length, and for the shortest word, for exiting early, an entirely [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#description)-based prefix-validation and -aggregation ...

```js
function longestCommonPrefix(arr) {
  const charList = [];

  const [shortestWord, ...wordList] =
    // sort shallow copy by item `length` first.
    [...arr].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);

  shortestWord
    .split('')
    .every((char, idx) => {
      const isValidChar = wordList.every(word =>
        word.charAt(idx) === char
      );
      if (isValidChar) {
        charList.push(char);
      }
      return isValidChar;
    });

  return charList.join('');
}

console.log(
  longestCommonPrefix(["flower","flow","flight"])
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Excellent solution sir, had the same idea and your example helped me fix my bug(lack of shallow copy).

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
strs[i][j] == strs[i + 1][j] ==strs[i + 2][j]
```

makes no sense in JS... or at least, makes no sense in what you are doing... to do this you should use a `&&` operator, like this:

```
strs[i][j] == strs[i + 1][j] && strs[i + 1][j] ==strs[i + 2][j]
```

Otherwise JS will evaluate the first condition, and then will evaluate the result of that operation (either `true` or `false`) with the third value

In addition to this, consider that you are looping with `i` over the array, and so `i` will also be `str.length - 1` but in the condition you are referencing `strs[i + 2][j]` that will be in that case `strs[str.length + 1][j]` that in your case, makes no sense.

About the solution:
You should consider that the prefix is common to all the values in the array, so you can take in consideration one value, and just check if all the other are equals... the most obvious is the first one, and you will end up with something like this:

```js
let strs = ["flower", "flow", "flight", "dix"];

function longestCommonPrefix (strs) {
  // loop over the characters of the first element
  for (let j = 0; j < strs[0].length; j++) {
    // ignore the first elements since is obvious that is equal to itself
    for (let i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
       /* in case you have like 
        [
          'banana',
          'bana'
        ]
        the longest prefix is the second element
       */
       if(j >= strs[i].length){
         return strs[i]
       }
       // different i-th element
       if(strs[0][j] != strs[i][j]){
         return strs[0].substr(0, j)
       }
       
    }
  }
  // all good, then the first element is common to all the other elements
  return strs[0]
};

console.log(longestCommonPrefix(strs));
```

Comment: Explaining _why_ it doesn't make sense (since the first == will yield a boolean, so the second == will always be false) would be a good edit.

Comment: @Alberto Sinigaglia Thank you so much for your help and what should I change in my code so I can iterate for the next character check? Please have a look at the question also.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans _Otherwise JS will evaluate the first condition, and then will evaluate the result of that operation (either true or false) with the third value_ isn't enough?

Comment: @HarshMishra I've posted a possible solution

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia I have given the upvote on your answer. So, it makes it zero. No worries, your solution is what I was looking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not a correct solution. For one, it may return before having looked at all strings... For example, ["aaa", "aaaaaa", "what"] should result in an empty string, but this code returns "aa".

Comment: this solution doesn't work,  ```["flower", "flow", "flight", "dix"];``` returns `flo` even though `flower` doesn't share any prefix with `dix`

Comment: @trincot yes you are right, i've mistyped `i` instead of `j`

Comment: @hanshenrik yes you are right, i've mistyped `i` instead of `j`

Comment: @HarshMishra be aware that there was a typo... btw I would suggest you to check  derpirscher answer that is pretty neat

Answer (score 1):

not the best solution but this should work

```js
function longestPrefix(strs){
    if(strs.length <1){
        return "";
    }
    const sharedPrefix=function(str1,str2){
        let i=0;
        for(;i<Math.min(str1.length,str2.length) /*todo optimize*/;++i){
            if(str1[i] !== str2[i]){
                break;
            }
        }
        return str1.substr(0,i);
    };
    let curr = strs[0];
    for(let i=1;i<strs.length;++i){
        curr=sharedPrefix(curr,strs[i]);
        if(curr.length < 1){
            // no shared prefix
            return "";
        }
    }
    return curr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are here for Leetcode problem solution.

```
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
let arr = strs.concat().sort();
const a1 = arr[0];
const a2 = arr[arr.length -1];
const length = a1.length;
let i=0;

while(i<length && a1.charAt(i) == a2.charAt(i)) i++;
return a1.substring(0,i);

};
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this, it works fast enough ~ 110ms

```
 function longestCommonPrefix(strs){
  if (strs.length === 0) {
    return ''
  }
    
  const first = strs[0];
  let response = ''; 
  let prefix = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
    prefix += first[i];
    let find = strs.filter(s => s.startsWith(prefix));
    if (find.length === strs.length) {
      response = prefix;
    }

  }
  return response;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let strs = ["flower", "flow", "flight"];

var longestCommonPrefix = function (strs) {
  for (let i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < strs[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(strs[i+2][j]);
      if (strs[i][j] == strs[i + 1][j] && strs[i][j]  ==strs[i + 2][j]) {
        return (strs[i][j]);
        


      } else {
        return "0";
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(longestCommonPrefix(strs));
```

This **return ** f

Answer (score 0):

Increase the index while the letter is the same at that index for all words in the list. Then slice on it.

```
function prefix(words) {
  if (words.length === 0) { return '' }
  let index = 0;
  while (allSameAtIndex(words, index)) {
    index++;
  }
  return words[0].slice(0, index);
}

function allSameAtIndex(words, index) {
  let last;
  for (const word of words) {
    if (last !== undefined && word[index] !== last[index]) {
      return false;
    }
    last = word;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function prefixLen(s1, s2) {
    let i = 0;
    while (i <= s1.length && s1[i] === s2[i]) i++;
    return i;
}

function commonPrefix(arr) {
    let k = prefixLen(arr[0], arr[1]);
    for (let i = 2; i < arr.length; i++) {
        k = Math.min(k, prefixLen(arr[0], arr[i]));
    }
    return arr[0].slice(0, k);
}

console.log(commonPrefix(['pirate', 'pizza', 'pilates']))  // -> "pi"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
    let prefix = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < strs[0].length; i++) {
        for(let j = 1; j < strs.length; j++) {
            if(strs[j][i] !== strs[0][i]) return prefix;
        }
        prefix = prefix + strs[0][i];
    }
    return prefix;
};
console.log(longestCommonPrefix);
```

Comment: Can you just explain what did you change and why your answer will fix the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as one loop and compare each element of the strings

```
const longestPrefix = (strs) => {
[word1, word2, word3] = strs;
let prefix = [];
if(strs === null || strs.length <= 2 || strs.length > 3) return 'please 
insert 3 elements'

for (let i=0; i < word1.length; i++){ 
        if(word1[i] ===  word2[i] && word1[i] === word3[i]){
            prefix.push(word1[i])
        }
}
return prefix.join('')
}
```

Comment: What if someone wants to find the longest prefix of 4 words? Or 1000?

Answer (score 0):

```
const findPrefix = (strs) => {
    let broke = false;
    return strs[0].split("").reduce(
        (acc, curr, index) =>
            broke || !strs.every((word) => word[index] === curr)
                ? (broke = true && acc)
                : (acc += curr),

        ""
    );
};

console.log(findPrefix(["flower", "flow", "flamingo"]));
```

Comment: I used a boolean as an escape case to avoid false positives.
I'm interested in learning what can be considered wrong with this code since I have very little experience writing algorithms

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72517845/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I read in another answer: 'Increase the index while the letter is the same at that index for all words in the list. Then slice on it.'

that's how I came up with this:

```
const findPrefix = (strs) => {
    let i = 0;
    while (strs.every((item) => strs[0][i] === item[i])) {
        i++;
    }
    return strs[0].slice(0, i);
};

console.log(findPrefix(["flo", "flow", "flomingo"]));
```

Comment: Instead of just copying from my answer, you should try to understand it ... Have you tried your code  with an array just containing a single word, like `findPrefix(["foo"])`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, Today I had an interview and the dev asked me the same question, I think I failed because I got stuck hahaha kinda nervous when someone is watching me , anyway I decided to figure it out after the interview is done and this is my answer (without google it I swear) and for those who don't feel comfortable with the common "for loop"

```js
 const arr = ["absence", "absolute", "absolutely", "absorb"]
  function getPrefix(arr) {
    if (arr.length === 0 || arr.some(s => !s)) return null //if it's an empty array or one of its values is null or '', return null
    const first = arr[0].split("") // turns the first position of the array, into an array
    const res = arr.map(w => {
      // mapping the original array
      const compare = w.split("") // every item of the array will be converted in another array of its characters
      return first.map((l, idx) => (compare[idx] === l ? l : "")).join("") // loop through the "first" array and compare each character
    })
    const prefix = first.join("").startsWith(res[res.length - 1]) // compare if the first letter starts with the last item of the returned array
      ? res[res.length - 1] // if true, return the final response which is the prefix
      : null // else, return null, which means there is no common prefix
    console.log("prefix: ", prefix)
    return prefix
  }
  
  getPrefix(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = ["flower", "flow", "flight"]

function checkPrefix(array) {

    let index = []
    for (let i = 0; i <= array[0].length; i++) {

        if (check(array[0][i], i, array)) {
            index.push(i)
        } else {
            break;
        }

    }

    console.log(array[0].substring(index[0], index[index.length - 1] + 1));

}

const check = (str, index, stringArr) => {
    debugger
    let status = true
    stringArr.map(ele => {
        debugger
        if (ele[index] != str) {
            status = false
        }
    })
    return status
}

checkPrefix(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @param {string[]} strs
 * @return {string}
 */
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
  let compare = strs[0];
  let str = "";
  for (let i = 1; i < strs.length; i++) {
    let  j = 0;
    while(compare[j] != undefined && strs[i][j] != undefined) {
        if(strs[i][j] == compare[j]) {
            str += strs[i][j];
        }
        else break;
        j++;
    }
    compare = str;
    str = "";
  }

  return compare;
};
```

Comment: How does your answer improve on any of the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

**Longest common prefix in Javascript** *(All test case accepted. Asked by many company interviews.)*

```
  var longestCommonPrefix = function (strs) {
  let string = '';
  if (strs.length > 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < strs[0].length; i++) {
      let str = strs[0].charAt(i);
      for (let s = 0; s < strs.length - 1; s++) {
        if (!(strs[s + 1].charAt(i) && strs[s].charAt(i) && strs[s + 1].charAt(i) == strs[s].charAt(i))) {
          str = '';
        }
      }
      if (!str) {
        break;
      }
      string += str;

    }
    return string;
  } else {
    return strs[0];
  }

};
longestCommonPrefix(["flower","flow","flight"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Code to find longest prefix

```
var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
    let match = false;
    let len = strs[0].length ;
    let ans = "";
    let prev_ans ="";
    
    if(strs.length ==1){
        return strs[0];
    }
    
    for (let i = 1; i < strs.length; i++){
        if( strs[i-1].length > strs[i].length){
            len = strs[i].length;
        }    
    }  

    for (let i = 1; i < strs.length; i++){

        for (let j = 0; j < len; j++){
            if(strs[i-1].charAt(j) == strs[i].charAt(j)){
                ans += strs[i-1].charAt(j);
                match = true;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
        
        if(prev_ans != "" && prev_ans !=ans){
           
           if(prev_ans.length > ans.length){
               return ans;
           }else{
               return prev_ans;
           }
        }
         prev_ans = ans;
         ans = "";
       if (match == false){
            return "";
        }
    } 
    
    return prev_ans;

};
console.log(longestCommonPrefix(["flow","fly","flu"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
function longestCommonPrefix(...words) {
  words.sort(); // shortest string will be first and the longest last
  return (
    words[0].split('') // converts shortest word to an array of chars
      .map((char, idx) => words[words.length - 1][idx] === char ? char : '\0') // replaces non-matching chars with NULL char
      .join('') // converts back to a string
      .split('\0') // splits the string by NULL characters
      .at(0) // returns the first part
  );
}
```

Usage example:

```
longestCommonPrefix('abca', 'abda', 'abea'); // 'ab'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const strs = ["flower", "flow", "flight"];

var longestCommonPrefix = function (strs) {
  var answer = "";
  var sub = strs[0];
  var match = true;
  for (let i = 0; i < sub.length; i++) {
    var value = sub[i];
    for (let j = 1; j < strs.length; j++) {
      var checkString = strs[j];
      if (checkString[i] !== value) {
        match = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (match === false) {
      break;
    } else {
      answer = answer + value;
    }
  }

  return answer;
};

longestCommonPrefix(strs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const longestCommonPrefix= (input)=>{
  let prefix = '';
  input.forEach(element=>{
    for(let i=0;i<element.length;i++){
      let c= element[i];
      let isSame = input.every(str=>str[i] ==c);
      if(isSame){
        if(!prefix.includes(c))
          prefix+=c;
      }else{
        return prefix;
      }
    }
  })
  return prefix;
}
longestCommonPrefix(["flower","flow","flight"])); //fl
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
let testcases = [
  ["flower", "flow"], //should return "flow"
  ["flower", "flow", "flight"],  //should return "fl"
  ["flower", "flow", "fight"],  //should return "f"
  ["flower", "flow", "floor"],  //should return "flo"
  ["flower"], //should return "flower"
]

var longestCommonPrefix = function(strs) {
  for(var i=0; i<strs.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<strs[i].length; j++){
      if(strs[i][j] + strs[i][j+1] === strs[i+1][j]+strs[i+1][j+1]){
        return strs[i][j]+strs[i][j+1];
      }
      else {
        return "";
      }
    }
  }
};


for (let strs of testcases)
  console.log(longestCommonPrefix(strs));
```

Comment: Have you tried your approach with arrays like `["flower", "flow", "floor"]` or  `["flower", "flow", "fight"]` ? It will return `fl` in both of those cases, which is obviously wrong. Because for the first one it should return `flo` for the second one `f`. The only thing it does, is comparing the first two characters of the first two elements of the array

Comment: I added some more testcases to your code. They all return the same result, which is obviously wrong. Except the last one, which crashes, even if the input meets the specified requirements.