# A seemingly simple question about how to return null in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

This is driving me insane, because I feel like it shouldn't be a problem for me, and yet, here I am hoping one of you will take mercy on me. This function takes an array of strings and returns the longest common prefix. It seems to do that fine. The problem is that I want it to return null if there is no common prefix. Instead it returns nothing. With this particular input, it's comparing the first letter in all words from index 1 onward to the first letter in the word at index 0. It gets to sunflower, sees that f !== s, but instead of returning null, I get nothing at all. What am I missing?

```js
function prefix(words) {
  for (let i = 0; i < words[0].length; i++) {
    const char = words[0][i];
    for (let j = 1; j < words.length; j++) {
      if (i === words[j].length || words[j][i] !== char) {
        return words[0].substring(0, i);
      } 
    }
  }
  // No common prefix found
  return null;
}
console.log(prefix(["flower", "flowers", "floyd", "flow", "sunflower", "floor"]))
```

Comment: AFAIK For has no else statement, Meaning you got to tuck it in an `if-else` statement, that if words is filled, then you execute the for statement, else return the null. Now, accordding to your code, it will return actually always return northing. Even if it loops through your words variable.

Comment: Can you please explain "_Instead it returns nothing_"? JS function returns `undefined`, if the return value isn't specified.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68702774/longest-common-prefix-in-javascript) answer your question? You can replace the 0 with null.

Comment: In the environment I'm using, which is a LeetCode playground, it gives me nothing. I added in a ton of console.logs to show what it's doing at every step, and where it should say null at the end, it's just the last console.log instead.

Comment: What happens if you run it in a plain JS environment, not Leetcode? You can even make it an executable snippet here with the [<>] button.

Comment: @deceze I get undefined

Comment: So it’s something specific about Leetcode… ‍♂️

Comment: @deceze I guess I just don't understand why it would return undefined in my console and nothing in LeetCode, when I have 'return null' at the end.

Comment: @Hamada I really appreciate that, I just want to understand why it isn't working as expected the way I have it written. It seems like there should be a way to get it to work this way without starting over with a new approach. And if not, then I want to figure out why not.

Comment: It's not returning _nothing_ — it's returning an empty string: `""`.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify the code a bit and return null if there's no more than one iteration to check the prefix. Also you could add an extra check for empty or 1 word arrays, otherwise your code would fail.

```js
function prefix(words) {
    if(words.length < 2 || words[0] === '') { // extra check for 0 or 1 words
      return words[0] || null;
    }
    let i = 0;
    while (true) {
        const c = words[0][i];
        for (let j = 1; j < words.length; j++) {
            if (c != words[j][i]) {
                return i ? words[0].slice(0, i) : null;
            }
        }
        i++; // this will happen when at least 1 character is common
    }
}
console.log(prefix([]));
console.log(prefix(['']));
console.log(prefix(['', '']));
console.log(prefix(['flower', '']));
console.log(prefix(['flower']));
console.log(prefix(["flower", "flowers", "floyd", "flow", "floor"]))
console.log(prefix(["flower", "flowers", "floyd", "flow", "sunflower", "floor"]))
```

And a benchmark:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="10000000">

const words = ["flower", "flowers", "floyd", "flow", "floor"];

// @benchmark museum/tom
    function prefix(words) {
      for (let i = 0; i < words[0].length; i++) {
        const char = words[0][i];
        for (let j = 1; j < words.length; j++) {
          // first letter unequal
          if (i === 0 && words[j][i] !== char) {
            return null;
          }
          if (i === words[j].length || words[j][i] !== char) {
            return words[0].substring(0, i);
          } 
        }
      }
      // No common prefix found
      return null;
    }
    // @run
    prefix(words);

// @benchmark Alexander
    function prefix2(words) {
        if(words.length < 2 || words[0] === '') { // extra check for 0 or 1 words
          return words[0] || null;
        }
        let i = 0;
        while (true) {
            const c = words[0][i];
            for (let j = 1; j < words.length; j++) {
                if (c != words[j][i]) {
                    return i ? words[0].slice(0, i) : null;
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    // @run
    prefix2(words);
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Less than 500 milliseconds for 10 million iterations

Comment: @JaDa i'm on i-12600k

Answer (score 0):

Here's what's happening

In the case of `["flower", "flowers", "floyd", "flow", "sunflower", "floor"]`, the loop iterates through the characters of the first word and compares them to the other words.

When `i` reaches the length of the first word **(i = 5)**, there is no exit condition for the outer loop, so it continues to the next iteration.

However, there's no corresponding character in the other words, so the inner loop conditions `(i === words[j].length || words[j][i] !== char)` are not met.

Since the loop completes without returning anything and all the words are not the same, the function ends without a return statement.

In JavaScript, when a function doesn't return anything, it returns `undefined`, and that's why you see nothing printed.

The fix for this is to add a return statement after the outer loop to handle the case where the loop completes without finding a common prefix.

```js
function prefix(words) {
    /* Check if words list is 0, since prefix will always be null
    in this case */
    if (words.length === 0) return null; 

    for (let i = 0; i < words[0].length; i++) {
        const char = words[0][i];
        for (let j = 1; j < words.length; j++) {
            if (i === words[j].length || words[j][i] !== char) {
                if (i === 0) return null;
                return words[0].substring(0, i);
            }
        }
    }

    return null; // Add this line to handle the missing case
}

console.log(
    prefix(['flower', 'flowers', 'floyd', 'flow', 'flinging', 'floor'])
); // output: null

console.log(
    prefix(['triangle', 'trick', 'trivial', 'triceratops', 'tricycle']) // output: 'tri'
);
```

Comment: I already have that return null there in that spot

Comment: There were 2 extra lines added in my response: checking if `i === 0` and returning null, and a guard case to return null. This response produced expected results when I ran it in nodejs.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that's working for me too. Can you explain to me like I'm a beginner why if (i === 0) doesn't return null immediately every time since i is initially 0?

Comment: While the outer loop starts with i = 0, the inner loop checks for a mismatch at the current position i across all the remaining words in the array. If there's no mismatch at the current character position, the inner loop continues to iterate, and nothing is returned. If there is a mismatch specifically at the position i = 0, meaning that the first character of the first word does not match the first character of one of the other words, then and only then the condition (i === 0) evaluates to true, and null is returned.

Comment: OK, I get it. Thanks so much. Please enjoy my upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the first character is not equal and in this case return null (or undefined):

```js
function prefix(words) {
  for (let i = 0; i < words[0].length; i++) {
    const char = words[0][i];
    for (let j = 1; j < words.length; j++) {
      // first letter unequal
      if (i === 0 && words[j][i] !== char) {
        return null;
      }
      if (i === words[j].length || words[j][i] !== char) {
        return words[0].substring(0, i);
      } 
    }
  }
  // No common prefix found
  return null;
}

console.log(prefix(["flower", "flowers", "floyd", "flow", "floor"]))
console.log(prefix(["flower", "flowers", "floyd", "flow", "sunflower", "floor"]))
```

Answer (score -2):

In your iterations for i=0 and j=4, your code is comparing 's' and 'f' -- which will give true for your if condition, but in that case you are returning substring(0,0) for that word which gives an empty string ('') and hence you are returning empty string and not null- so not seeing any thing in your output.
Hope this helps, any feedback is welcome.

I solved the problem in a different manner:

```js
function prefix(words) {
  // We need to return this prefix and if it is still an empty string we can return null
  let longestCommonPrefix = '';

  // To iterate and access one alphabet at a time
  for (let j = 0; j < words[0].length; j++) {
    // Curr alphabet that needs to be compared if all words have this alphabet in same j'th position, we add it to the prefix string
    let currChar = words[0][j];

    // To iterate over different words in the array
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      // If in any iteration the alphabet doesnt match the currChar, we can return the longestCommonPrefix
      if (words[i][j] !== currChar) {
        // Ternary operator if longestCommonPrefix has a value of empty string which has a boolean of false, we will return null for that
        return longestCommonPrefix ? longestCommonPrefix : null;
      }
    }

    longestCommonPrefix = longestCommonPrefix + currChar;
  }

  // No common prefix found
  return longestCommonPrefix ? longestCommonPrefix : null;
}

console.log(prefix(["flower", "flowers", "floyd", "flow", "sunflower", "floor"]))
```